# Does Chromecast MediaRouteButton have a production bug?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, chromecast

*** -- The issue is my APP ID so as not to waste anybody's time.

On the off chance this helps some other noob the real problem was I forgot to check the:

"Send serial device # to Google when checking for updates" checkbox below the fold on the Chromecast device setup application.

I also then had to reboot my Chromecast device for this to take effect.

Now Naddaf's github works fine!

---

Before beginning: I have no problem casting examples that use ActionBarActivity so my chromecast configuration is definitely not the issue.

In reference to:

https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

There seems to be a bug in that

mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);

located in: MediaRouterButtonActivity.java

NEVER receives a callback.

This was reported 4 days ago:

https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android/issues/5

**The long version:**

I have a mature beta of my video based Android app that uses FragmentActivity and currently targets SDK 14+.

I have set up a Chromecast device for development successfully and it works with the sample apps in SDK/Extras just fine. The problem there is they all are predicated on inheriting from ActionBarActivity which is mutually exclusive/incompatible with FragmentActivity.

Every example from StackOverflow or github (only one project) that I have tried that uses android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton does run only the MediaRouteButton never instantiates.

When tracing I see that the following is the issue:

mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);

The callback is added but the Chromecast SDK never calls back to it.

Google gives an entire walkthru using the ActionBarActivity but only makes a fleeting reference to the alternative use of the MediaRouteButton.

I have now wasted 2 days already trying to wrap my head around this but guessing one's way through it sub-optimal.

Is there anybody who has a working example of using the MediaRouteButton with FragmentActivity or a link to working documentation. This is now seeming like a major oversight by the Chromecast team.

Thanks!

Comment: I just grabbed the source form the Github, added my App ID,  compiled and ran that on my N5, running the publicly available Play services and it worked (i.e. showed devices) with no issue.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I am using with brand new Galaxy tab. Every other ActionBarActivity github project works with my App ID and casts to my TV. When I use the MediaRouteButton project every activity is just an empty screen. Any ideas?

Comment: PS - I am using Eclipse with latest SDK

Comment: This issue applies to all 4 buttons in the sample app. When I tap any button (MRD, MRB, MR Action Bar Button, MR Custom Dialog Button) I merely get an empty screen.

Comment: what app id are you using? What do you see in the logs?

Comment: I am using the App ID from my Chromecast developer console. I added it to the strings.xml resource. I do not see any errors in the logcat...

Comment: You seem to be implying it is my APP ID. I have successfully Chromecasted the SDK/Extras Tic Tac Toe sample project for Eclipse to the same APP ID so I was assuming my ID is good to go. My device is also apparently whitelisted. I would think the Tic Tac Toe app would not work if the issue were my App ID?

Comment: I apologize Ali. It is indeed my APP ID. I just went back and checked the Tic Tac Toe game and when I used my APP ID that failed too. When I used the APP ID it ships with in this project it shows the MediaRouteButton.